# Eureka: How do I disable/configure peer replication?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

When I run Eureka on port 8761, everything works great. The config server can register to Eureka without problem. When I change eureka port to 7001, however, things stop working and I can't seem to figure out how to fix them.

The issue seems to revolve around Eureka not being able to find a peer node running at: http://localhost:8761/eureka. The exception is:

```
2015-07-05 08:00:47.301 ERROR 4140 --- [egister-process] 
c.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNode  : PeerEurekaNode: 
http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/: CONFIGSERVER/localhost:Register
```

Indeed when Eureka starts, it says: Adding replica node: http://localhost:8761/eureka/. It seems thus that somewhere the a replica node is assumed to be running at 8761.

Is there a way to disable Eureka looking for replica nodes? Or how do I control if and when and where replica should happen? I looked at the EurekaServerConfig class (http://netflix.github.io/eureka/javadoc/eureka-core/index.html) but I could not find anything that goes in this direction.

This is with Spring Cloud 1.0.2.RELEASE.

Comment: please share your properties file. Did you change "defaultZone"?

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. I added eureka.serviceUrl.defaultZone to eureka application.yml file. Please add your comment as answer and I will accept it if you so wish.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to configure `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` property in application.yml file.

Comment: Are you sure that the property name is [still] correct?
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone
from the @B-ron's answer helped me instead.

Comment: I've updated the answer to the current correct property